# How do i delete all browsing data from all browser via command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a batch script to delete all browsing data from all browser via command line.
But it fails and doesn't clear all data.
It only deletes all the chrome data.
IE and firefox data isnt being deleted.

This works fine
for chrome:

```
set ChromeDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"
rd /s /q "%ChromeDir%"
```

for firefox

```
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"

for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
```

it does not delete all data.

for IE

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255
```

This is also not working.
Please help me.
i am using windows 8.1 IE 11.
Is any other way to do this easily.
via command line.

Answer (score 0):

So i tried the commands for firefox and IE11 both work for me. Are you running the script as administrator?

I changed the firefox command abit see below:

```
set DataDir=%loaclappdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"

for /d %%x in (%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
```

As an alternitive you could use CCleaner command-line the command below will run ccleaner and clean using your default settings then close the program.

```
Cd "C:\Program Files\CCleaner"
ccleaner.exe /Cleaner /AUTO
```

You will have to change this command depending on if you use 32bit or 64bit windows

Are you planing on using this on a network ?